# Self-vote and anti-self-electors

Tags: election, presidential-election, ethics

In a presidential or similar elections, it's a habit, if one is a candidate, to get to the polling place, and vote, usually in the storm of camera flashes, from propaganda reasons, so self-voting is expected.

Are there known cases (in any country) when the candidate intentionally from ethical reasons did not vote, or even stated that he/she voted the competitor?

Comment: How would voting for yourself be in anyway unethical?

Comment: And if some candidate had second thoughts about how adequate s/he is for the position... why not just cancel his candidature? That said, I could see this happenning in multi-seat constituencies in small populations; the need to present a minimum number of candidates even for marginal parties makes for some of the smaller ones including "fillers" (people who agree to be in the list so the list can be approved but who are not voters/supporters of the party)

Comment: @SleepingGod any related answer is good, but there probably will not bee the best/accented answer (unless it's a considerable list), since there can be many different "possibilities".

Comment: If they vote for the other candidate, what does that say about their confidence in their own ability? If they don't vote at all, what sort of example does that set? If one adheres to the civic responsibility associated with a vote, then I would expect every candidate to vote, and to vote for themselves as the person they believe to be the most qualified candidate.

Comment: @ThisIsNoZaku, I believe it can be considered a conflict of interest, because that person the he/she is going to vote is the same person, and will have financial and other benefits in the elected position; and therefore should abstain from vote.

Comment: It's not unusual for a candidate not to vote for themselves in a parliamentary system. If the candidate's home is not in the constituency for which they are standing, then they can't vote for themselves.  Catherine Taylor-Dawson received 1 vote in 2005, she didn't vote for herself as she was not registered there.